# How can add a DrawingGroup for MyUserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a custom control

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl { ... }
```

I get 'null' calling

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing(this)
```

How can I change MyUserControl to return non-null value? Any overloads, or what?

This is not a practical task, just a research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the documentation doesn't say anything about this, it seems that only returns a drawing for visuals that implement OnRender functionality.  I tested it out on a shape, and also on a Window that overrode OnRender, and both returned the drawing.

However, if the Window doesn't override OnRender, the method returns null.  I also made the call after the controls had been loaded, in case you were not doing that.